# Linux script counter not working correctly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, counter

im doing an assignment where i have to make a script, and it doesn't seem to be adding to the counter  to display the clues when the counter reaches a certain number Here is the code below

```
#!/bin/bash
#This is a game that is played by the user having to guess a number that the computer thinks of.
counter=0
# functions
function clueOne() {
 echo “The number is over 50”
 return
}
function clueTwo() {
 echo “The number is smaller than 100 and is devided by 7, 10 times”
 return
}


function selectANumber() {
 dialog --backtitle "Number Game" --title "Number Game" --infobox "Thinking of a number..." 
10 50 ; clear
}
selectANumber
# game starts here
while [ $counter  -le 10 ];  do
 read -p ”Guess my number human!”
 if [ $counter -eq 5 ]; 
 then 
 clueOne
 counter=$((counter+1))
 elif [ $counter -eq 9 ]; 
 then
 clueTwo
 counter=$((counter+1))
 elif [ $REPLY = 70 ]; 
 echo “Yes that is my number!”; 
 exit 1
 echo “Wrong number”
 counter=$((counter+1))
fi
done
echo “Sorry you ran out of attempts”
```

Answer (score 0):

Because if your counter us 0 say you wont go in any of if else ladder. So you may want to increment your counter variable just before done i.e. in while loop like:

```
counter=$((counter+1))
```

And remove the increment operation from if else ladder.

Comment: Sorry im a bit new at this, how exactly would i do it?

Comment: If you think it helped, close this question by accepting the answer.